# What is good practice for securing/authorizing a REST-service for server-to-server communication?

Tags: security

What good techniques exist to secure server-to-server REST-communication ?
For communication involving human devices, like browsers, mobile phone, OAuth and SAML are good choices, but are they also best choice for server-to-server transactions?

I am mostly interested in protocol/application layer techniques.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a really broad question question where you won't have a single one size fits all solution and quite often you might stack multiple approaches.

You might secure and authenticate primarily at the network layer, with running your services only in a specific network segment. Requiring a VPN connection or IPSec also falls under such an approach.

Firewalls are always a good idea, deny everything by default, open only what's explicitly allowed.
Servers typically have static ip-addresses allowing much more restrictive ACLs compared to public services.

You might want to secure and authenticate on the protocol layer, https and plain username/password (or other authentication) or HTTPS and mutual authentication with client certificates.

You might want to secure and authenticate the actual messages that get transmitted and would consider something like HMAC.

And probably many more, also depending on how much of the environment you control.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know it was broad and I appreciate your effort to answer it as such. I am primarily looking for suggestions in the application layer. Maybe just keywords, e.g. "OAUTH with API Key", so I can search and find specific descriptions via Google.

Comment: Than ServerFault might not be the optimal platform as such is much more a result of how an application is designed rather than how it gets deployed by an administrator/engineer. [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7999295/2952385) might be a better place, as might be [Security.se](http://security.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=rest%20api)

Comment: Thanks, I guess you are right. I'll repost it in Security.